Postgres lock using linux and xk6-sql
I got a Postgres db in docker, API service in docker, local xk6-sql and linux xk6-sql build in azure pipelines
Locally (xk6 on windows laptop and docker desktop) all requests and db queries work fine in any order, but when i run the same test on linux agent in azure, xk6-sql can't read or write the rows which were read ot written by the service in db (the SELECT query returns empty object) and vice versa - API responses return empty body/value reading from xk6 edited table rows
Tried sleeps after every operation, tried SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid() to reset all locks but it doesn't work ...Where else should i dig?
here's the yaml deployment in linux

- bash: |
      cd $(dirname "${{ parameters.testFilePath}}")
      sudo gpg -k
      sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/k6-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C5AD17C747E3415A3642D57D77C6C491D6AC1D69
      echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/k6-archive-keyring.gpg] https://dl.k6.io/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/k6.list
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install k6
      export GOPATH=$HOME/go
      export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
      go install go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest
      xk6 build --with github.com/szkiba/xk6-dashboard@latest
      go install github.com/grafana/xk6-dashboard/cmd/k6-web-dashboard@latest
      xk6 build --with github.com/grafana/xk6-sql --with github.com/grafana/xk6-sql-driver-postgres
    displayName: Install xk6

  - bash: |
      cd $(dirname "${{ parameters.testFilePath }}")
      export GOPATH=$HOME/go
      export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin:/usr/bin/go
      K6_WEB_DASHBOARD=true K6_WEB_DASHBOARD_PERIOD=1s K6_WEB_DASHBOARD_EXPORT=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/k6-test-results/html-report.html ./k6 run --out json=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/k6-test-results/test-result.json ${{ parameters.testFilePath }}
    displayName: Run Tests in K6`

--------------------------------------test-----------------------------------------
//Service inserting values in db.a

//xk6 INSERT query in db.b 


let tenant = db.query("SELECT * FROM db.a WHERE tenant_id = $1;", "35acae14-f7cb-468a-9866-1fc45713149a");
                
let aggr = db.query("SELECT * FROM db.b WHERE tenant_id = $1;", "07f48e4f-5b73-4a83-93b7-5f2231f817b6");

try {
console.log('tenant by ads-service', Object.toString(tenant))
console.log('tenant by ads-service', String.fromCharCode(...tenant[0].tenant_id))  
} catch (error) {}
try {
console.log('tenant by xk6-postgres', Object.toString(tenant))
console.log('tenant by xk6-postgres',String.fromCharCode(...tenant[0].tenant_id))  
} catch (error) {}


//Local output
INFO[0025] tenant by ads-service function Object() { [native code] }  source=console
INFO[0025] tenant by ads-service 35acae14-f7cb-468a-9866-1fc45713149a  source=console                                                                                                                                                                                                         
INFO[0025] tenant by xk6-postgres function Object() { [native code] }  source=console                                                                                                                                                                                                         
INFO[0025] tenant by xk6-postgres 07f48e4f-5b73-4a83-93b7-5f2231f817b6  source=console 

//CI output 
    level=info msg="tenant by ads-service function Object() { [native code] }" source=console
    //^it returns empty object like []
    level=info msg="tenant by xk6-postgres function Object() { [native code] }" source=console
    level=info msg="tenant by xk6-postgres 2238d116-b461-4430-919c-cb15320b9152" source=console      

    ```
                                                                                                                                                                                                 

